# XCode Project configurations, CocoaPods, Dependencies and Static Libraries

Tags: objective-c, xcode, dependencies, cocoapods, libraries

Handling with CocoaPods as an external library to be accessible to all projects in the workspace, transitive dependencies with static library of ‍‍‍‍‍`GoogleMapsBase.framewor‍‍‍‍k‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍`, `GoogleMaps.framework`, and others from Google.

Problem: Problem on installing dependencies

Error:

> The 'project-name' target has transitive dependencies that include
>   static binaries.

What is the best way to keep all updated in CocoaPods, and make CocoaPods accessible to all project including libraries